# HTML 5 Drag & Drop Functionality - Remove Dropped Item

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm almost there.  I'm creating drag and drop functionality and the last part i'm having issues with is finding a clean way to remove the item that has been dropped.

The yellow div is draggable.  The red div is droppable.  When the yellow div is dragged on top of the red div, the red div turns blue.

When the yellow div is dropped, blue turns green to show that it has been dropped.

After this step, I want the yellow div to simply be deleted or style.display = 'none'.

Here is a snippet with everything working except removing the yellow div:

```js
    function dragOver(ev, id) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'blue';
    }

    function stopDrop(ev, id){
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'red';       
    }

    function dragStart(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function dropped(ev, id) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'green';         
    }
```

```css
div{padding:10px; margin:10px;}
div:nth-child(even){background:yellow;}
div:nth-child(odd){background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="drop" ondrop="dropped(event, this.id)" ondragover="dragOver(event, this.id)" ondragleave="stopDrop(event, this.id);" ondragend="disableDrop(event);">drop here</div>
<div id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">drag this</div>
```

An additional question: I'm passing the parameter (`this.id`) on the event listeners so that I can find the element later to change the color.  Is there a way to simply pass the entire object itself?  I tried `this` instead of `this.id` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just changing the background of the droppable, not actually moving the draggable. If you want to move it then add the following lines to dropped function:

```
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

if you just want to change the display of draggable, then try this:

```
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
document.getElementById(data).style.display = 'none';
```

Edit:
Regarding the id, you don't need to pass it to the function. You can get it from event like `ev.target.id`, or just directly use the `target`. Edited the code below as well.

===

The modified code:

```js
function dragOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.style.background = 'blue';
}

function stopDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.style.background = 'red';  
}

function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dropped(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById(data).style.display = 'none';
    ev.target.style.background = 'green';   
}
```

```css
div{padding:10px; margin:10px;}
div:nth-child(even){background:yellow;}
div:nth-child(odd){background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="drop" ondrop="dropped(event, this.id)" ondragover="dragOver(event, this.id)" ondragleave="stopDrop(event, this.id);" ondragend="disableDrop(event);">drop here</div>
<div id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">drag this</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked out perfectly.  Thank you.  Any thoughts on my usage of 'this.id' being passed as a parameter?  Is there an efficient way I can pass the entire element reference?  So that way I don't have to do: document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'red'; rather I could so something like this.style.background='red'.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can get the id from the event through `ev.target.id`. See the edit.

Comment: amazing!  thank you.  learn something new every time i come here.

Comment: Or instead of getting the `id` directly use the target. Like for changing background you can use `ev.target.style.background = 'green';`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/mcsab3aa/5/

```
function dragOver(ev, id) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'blue';
}

function stopDrop(ev, id) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'red';
}

function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
}

function dropped(ev, id) {
    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
}
```

You just needed to add text/html vs Text

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this did not work.  After dragging the yellow box, the yellow box remains.  The desired action was for it to disappear.

Comment: are you sure for me it does disappear? as in get deleted.

Comment: yes, unfortunately.  i've tried again on Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135